# Server 2008 Active directory file sharing Restriction

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, file-sharing

My network scenario is:

Two location connected each other through Wireless towers.
  1st network ip address are 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.150
  2nd network ip address are 10.10.10.200 to 10.10.10.254

Both location using their own ACTIVE DIRECTORY (MS SERVER 2008) and share their data with each other network through file sharing.

My Problem is that every single client can explore the whole network. by simply typing \computername. i want to implement some restriction on network regarding file sharing.

i want to restrict 1st Network Clients to open 2nd network Computer or server. 
Is there have any Group Policy or Folder permission scenario that i implement on my both network..

Comment: What does "both location using their own ACTIVE DIRECTORY" mean?  Different forest, different domain or just different DCs?

Comment: Just different DCs

Answer (score 1):

I *suppose* that you could do something involving Group Policy settings for the Windows Firewall, but you'd really be better served with a firewall device limiting the traffic between different parts of the network to achieve your goal of compartmentalization.

Your network addresses look suspiciously like they're both part of the same /24 network. That's going to make using a layer 3 device, like a firewall, problematic.

I also strongly suspect that using well thought-out access control lists (ACLs) on shared files and folders could probably accomplish a lot of what you're looking for without having to resort to network-level filtering.